# React onClick method autofires when the app has refreshed in the browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my method:

```
// jshint esversion: 6
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Forgot from './LoginForm/Forgot.js';
import RememberMe from './LoginForm/RememberMe.js';

class LoginForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.props = props;
        this.state = {
            pic1: '//ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png'
        };
    }

    _login(client){
        let username = document.getElementById('inputEmail').value;
        let password = document.getElementById('inputPassword').value;
        this.options = {
            username: username,
            password: password
        };
        client.login(this.options, (success, data)=>{
            if (success) {
                console.log('You are now logged in', data);
            }else{
                console.log('Details incorrect or something went wrong.');
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="card card-container">
                    <img id="profile-img" className="profile-img-card" src={this.state.pic1} />
                    <p id="profile-name" className="profile-name-card"></p>
                    <form className="form-signin">
                        <span id="reauth-email" className="reauth-email"></span>
                        <input type='text' id="inputEmail" className="form-control" placeholder="Username"></input>
                        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" className="form-control" placeholder="Password"></input>
                        <button className="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block btn-signin" type="submit" onClick={this._login(this.props.client)}>Login</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default LoginForm;
```

Every time my app refreshes in the browser I get this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
LoginForm._login
C:/wamp64/www/myreact/src/components/LoginForm.js:17
  14 | }
  15 | 
  16 | _login(client){
> 17 |  let username = document.getElementById('inputEmail').value;
  18 |  let password = document.getElementById('inputPassword').value;
  19 |  this.options = {
  20 |      username: username,
```

But I get that without clicking on the button. Why would react automatically  trigger the onClick method?
Is the error caused by passing through the `client` variable from props? For passing variables/methods to and from components Should I be storing variables/methods in the `state` instead of passing it from the parent component?

This is how I pass in my variable - Is it correct?:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this._client = deepstream('ws://localhost:6020');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <LoginForm client={this._client}></LoginForm>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: because you call the _login function > this._login(this.props.client) use this._login.bind(this.props.client) instead

Comment: Thanks, thats awesome. @AshKander Am I passing in the variable correctly?

Comment: I would add `this._login = this._login.bind(this)` in your constructor then just reference `this.props.client` from within `_login()` rather than passing it in as a parameter.

Comment: Or you could use an arrow function in `onClick`

Comment: @Xotic750 Surely having inline functions like that would be bad?

Comment: Bad in what way? Many prefer that method over Function#bind in the constructor. Either way will work, I guess it's mostly a style question, I don't think you would possibly notice any performance issues, if that is what you are thinking?

Comment: @Xotic750 Bad from a readability point of view. I agreed there would be little to no difference in performance. Just from keeping things nice and tidy. Especially considering that my login function is going to be a little bigger. Additionally, do you have any thoughts as to my second question - the `this.props.client` seems to be just a string instead of the class/set of methods imported.

Comment: You could assign the arrow function to a const in render and inline the reference in onClick, and it is nearer to the source than in the constructor, so it could be argued that it aids readability, when used well. I'm not really sure what deepstream is doing, but that could be problematic, hard to tell. It is always better/best/required to post single questions on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarise the comments with examples.

You are calling the `this._login` function in `onClick` during rendering  rather than assigning the function to be called when clicked.

Using the Function#bind suggestion by Doug Coburn

```js
// jshint esversion: 6
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Forgot from './LoginForm/Forgot.js';
import RememberMe from './LoginForm/RememberMe.js';

class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props = props;
    this.state = {
      pic1: '//ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png',
    };

    this._login = this._login.bind(this);
  }

  _login() {
    const username = document.getElementById('inputEmail').value;
    const password = document.getElementById('inputPassword').value;
    this.options = {
      username,
      password,
    };
    this.props.client.login(this.options, (success, data) => {
      if (success) {
        console.log('You are now logged in', data);
      } else {
        console.log('Details incorrect or something went wrong.');
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="card card-container">
          <img id="profile-img" className="profile-img-card" src={this.state.pic1} />
          <p id="profile-name" className="profile-name-card" />
          <form className="form-signin">
            <span id="reauth-email" className="reauth-email" />
            <input type="text" id="inputEmail" className="form-control" placeholder="Username" />
            <input type="password" id="inputPassword" className="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
            <button className="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block btn-signin" type="submit" onClick={this.login}>Login</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LoginForm;
```

Using the arrow function suggestion

```js
// jshint esversion: 6
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Forgot from './LoginForm/Forgot.js';
import RememberMe from './LoginForm/RememberMe.js';

class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props = props;
    this.state = {
      pic1: '//ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png',
    };
  }

  _login(client) {
    const username = document.getElementById('inputEmail').value;
    const password = document.getElementById('inputPassword').value;
    this.options = {
      username,
      password,
    };
    client.login(this.options, (success, data) => {
      if (success) {
        console.log('You are now logged in', data);
      } else {
        console.log('Details incorrect or something went wrong.');
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    const login = () => this._login(this.props.client);
    
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="card card-container">
          <img id="profile-img" className="profile-img-card" src={this.state.pic1} />
          <p id="profile-name" className="profile-name-card" />
          <form className="form-signin">
            <span id="reauth-email" className="reauth-email" />
            <input type="text" id="inputEmail" className="form-control" placeholder="Username" />
            <input type="password" id="inputPassword" className="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
            <button className="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block btn-signin" type="submit" onClick={login}>Login</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LoginForm;
```

Both should solve your problem 1, provided I didn't make any mistake, feel free to argue which is better/best. :)

The second question should be split off into its own SO question, so that a definitive answer can be given.